# Unknown processors type "resourcedetection" for "resourcedetection"

Tags: open-telemetry

Running OT Collector with image `ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-releases/opentelemetry-collector:0.58.0`

In config.yaml I have,

```
    processors:
      batch:
      resourcedetection:
        detectors: [ env ]
        timeout: 2s
        override: false
```

The collector is deployed as a sidecar but it keeps failing with
`collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: unknown processors type "resourcedetection" for "resourcedetection" (valid values: [resource span probabilistic_sampler filter batch memory_limiter attributes])`

Any idea as to what is causing this? I haven't found any relevant documentation/question

Answer (score 3):

The [Resource Detection Processor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/resourcedetectionprocessor) is part of the [otelcol-contrib](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-releases/tree/main/distributions/otelcol-contrib) distro upstream and you'd hence would need to use `otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.58.0` (or the equivalent on your container registry of choice) for this processor to be available in your collector.

Comment: I see do you know how we can use this when deploying otel-col as a sidecar? I am referring to the collector yaml described here https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator#getting-started thanks

Comment: I figured it out by passing in image under spec. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to learn and would be good if you accept that answer as the correct one so others know as well. IDC about the points but really about helping folks to get over the initial hurdles as quick as possible ;)